# Excel VBA Login to IE Site

Tags: vba, excel

I am a VBA novice and new to Stack Overflow, even though I have been reading posts on here for a while.  I have searched a lot for an answer to my coding problem, but I can't seem to find the answer. I am trying to login to a website, navigate to a page, and then scrape data from that page.  I have started to build the code which I have parsed together from what I've found on the internet.  I can't seem to get IE to even put my credentials in the appropriate user and PW boxes after looking up their IDs using "get elements".  What I end up with is Run Time Error 424 - Object Required.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
'Open IE, navigate to the desired page and loop until fully loaded
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    site = "https://www.ivolatility.com/login.j"

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate site
    Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    End With

'Input the userid and password
    IE.Document.getElementById("username").Value = "xxxxxx"
    IE.Document.getElementById("password").Value = "xxxxxx"

'Click the "Search" button
    IE.Document.getElementById("login_go").Click

    Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
```

Comment: These elements have no such IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to use the HTML input element's *name* as its *id* The two are not necessarily the same although sometimes you will see.

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" size="10" class="s2" maxlength="63 ">
```

But that is not he case here. You need to treat the elements by theor names and not ids.

```
dim n as long  'this belongs at hte top witrh the other Dims

'Input the userid and password
For n = 0 To ie.document.getelementsbytagname("input").Length - 1
    With ie.document.getelementsbytagname("input")(n)
        Select Case LCase(.Name)
            Case "username"
                .Value = "xxxxxx"
            Case "password"
                .Value = "zzzzzz"
            Case "login_go"
                .Click
                n = 99999
            Case Else
                'ignore
        End Select
    End With
Next n
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

The click works in this case because the submit comes after the input elements named *username* and *password*.

Answer (score 1):

As there are no HTML elements with IDs "username", "password" and "login_go", the `Value` of null cannot be set.

If the structure of the document remains the same all the time, you may access these elements with indices:

```
IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(3).Value = "xxxxxx"     
IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(8).Value = "xxxxxx"
...
IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("form")(1).Submit
```