# Greyhound data import to excel macro formula

Tags: vba, excel

as part of a research project i need to extract as much data as possible from a webpage. The problem is to access each table i have to follow lots of links which I can't get to work automatically.

Its from a greyhound-data.com. So an example would be I want to extract all the racing stats for every dog that raced in swindon between 1st Jan 2017- 28th Feb 2018. When i put it in the search engine I get 57236 races in a table. I have to follow the link on name of race for each race..

http://www.greyhound-data.com/d?racename=&country=13000&startmonth=3&endmonth=2&startdate=2017&enddate=2018&maxdist=unlimitied&class=any&order=dateD&x=2

My biggest problem is I don't know how to say follow the various links. And I don't know how to loop multiple times - once for each of the races in the original list.

I have created the simple Macro query :

```
Sub GetData()

Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim strURL As String
Dim I As Integer

For I = 1 To 9
strURL = "http://www.greyhound-data.com/d?racename=&country=13000&startmonth=3&endmonth=2&startdate=2017&enddate=2018&maxdist=unlimitied&class=any&order=dateD&x=" + Trim(Str(I))

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE

.navigate strURL
Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Set doc = IE.Document
GetAllTables doc

.Quit

End With
Next I

End Sub

Sub GetAllTables(doc As Object)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim tbl As Object
Dim rw As Object
Dim cl As Object
Dim tabno As Long
Dim nextrow As Long
Dim I As Long

Set ws = Worksheets.Add

For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
tabno = tabno + 1
nextrow = nextrow + 1
Set rng = ws.Range("B" & nextrow)
rng.Offset(, -1) = "Table " & tabno
For Each rw In tbl.Rows
For Each cl In rw.Cells
rng.Value = cl.outerText
Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
I = I + 1
Next cl
nextrow = nextrow + 1
Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -I)
I = 0
Next rw
Next tbl

End Sub
```

it retrieves the all races data from the url automatically. But can not make the next step. on each page there is a "name of the race" tab and I need to get all the data on each page for each row. It is because I need to get the information of 1st place, 2nd place and third place.

Thanks for your time I know its a bit garbled!!

My new code after changes is looking like this:

```
Sub GetData()

Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim strURL As String
Dim I As Integer

For I = 1 To 9
strURL = "http://www.greyhound-data.com/d?racename=&country=13000&startmonth=3&endmonth=2&startdate=2017&enddate=2018&maxdist=unlimitied&class=any&order=dateD&x=" + Trim(Str(I))

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE

.navigate strURL
Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Set doc = IE.Document
GetAllTables doc

.Quit

End With
Next I

End Sub


Sub GetAllTables(doc As Object)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim tbl As Object
Dim rw As Object
Dim cl As Object
Dim tabno As Long
Dim nextrow As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim ThisLink As Object 'variable for <a> tags
Set ws = Worksheets.Add

For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
    tabno = tabno + 1
    nextrow = nextrow + 1
    Set rng = ws.Range("B" & nextrow)

    rng.Offset(, -1) = "Table " & tabno
    For Each rw In tbl.Rows
        For Each cl In rw.Cells
            rng.Value = cl.outerText
            Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
            I = I + 1
        Next cl
    nextrow = nextrow + 1
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -I)
    I = 0
    Next rw
Next tbl

I = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row with data

Do While Cells(I, 1).Value = "" 'will loop until first not blank found in column A (starting from last row of data, from end to start)
    For Each ThisLink In doc.getElementsByTagName("a") 'we check all <a> tags
        If ThisLink.innerText = Cells(I, 2).Value Then Cells(I, 1).Value = ThisLink.href 'If the innertext is the name of the race, in column A we add link
    Next ThisLink
    I = I - 1 'we decrease row position
Loop
End Sub
```

but the case is that it returns the empty table as in this link : https://imageshack.us/i/poC4yhEZp

Comment: You should do a Loop to print ALL "a" tags. you can print a list of them using `a.href`. Then try to be more precise to check what of those refs you want and then you can open each one of them

Comment: can you please clarify a bit more. I am not actually professional on this but would highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code, after you get all your data, will check every race from end of list to start of list. And it will add in column A the related link to race.

```
Sub GetAllTables(doc As Object)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim tbl As Object
Dim rw As Object
Dim cl As Object
Dim tabno As Long
Dim nextrow As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim ThisLink As Object 'variable for <a> tags
Set ws = Worksheets.Add

For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
    tabno = tabno + 1
    nextrow = nextrow + 1
    Set rng = ws.Range("B" & nextrow)

    rng.Offset(, -1) = "Table " & tabno
    For Each rw In tbl.Rows
        For Each cl In rw.Cells
            rng.Value = cl.outerText
            Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
            I = I + 1
        Next cl
    nextrow = nextrow + 1
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -I)
    I = 0
    Next rw
Next tbl

I = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row with data

Do While Cells(I, 1).Value = "" 'will loop until first not blank found in column A (starting from last row of data, from end to start)
    For Each ThisLink In doc.getElementsByTagName("a") 'we check all <a> tags
        If ThisLink.innerText = Cells(I, 2).Value Then Cells(I, 1).Value = ThisLink.href 'If the innertext is the name of the race, in column A we add link
    Next ThisLink
    I = I - 1 'we decrease row position
Loop
End Sub
```

In HTML all `<a>` tags are like this:

> ```
> <a href="d?r=4269456&z=F0K9jn">Henlow 26 Feb 2018 HT 5</a>
> ```

The **href** attribute contains the link related to text between `<a>` and `</a>`. You can get it with `a.href` in VBA

To know the text between `<a>` and `</a>` you can use `a.InnerText`

What i did is just a simple loop to check every `<a>` tag. If the InnerText matchs the value in the cell, then I get the `href` attribute.

This code will get you all the links you want in your question. Just adapt the code to your needs (I pasted them in column A, but maybe you want to do something else with them).

You need 2 references for this code to work;

1. **Microsoft HTML Object Library**
2. **Microsoft Internet Controls**

[image]

And this is the final result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time. 
what I did initially, actually changed my second part of the code and pasted yours but id doesn't work. It returns empty table.

Comment: Debug line by line. I tested it  combined with your `Sub GetData()` and it worked perfectly. It does loops 9 times and get all data

Comment: yes, you are right it loops 9 times but the result is as in the picture :( http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img924/5554/C4yhEZ.png                              I just combined mine and yours, maybe I do mistake in somewhere ..

Comment: How is now your full code? Edit your question and Add the new one. Don't remove the old one from question

Comment: Edited the first post , now you can see the full code view either old one and new one.

Comment: mmm. I copied the code and pasted it into a new Excel and it worked perfectly for me. Check image https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWCiE.jpg . Make sure you got references to **Microsoft HTML Object Library** and **Microsoft Internet Controls**.

Comment: Updated my answer with a screenshot of the references you need to activate

Comment: Found the issue , deleted the www from the beggining of the url and it worked now. the case is that It does not return me for required table :) I need to retrieve the table for each link in the first column in your screenshot.

Comment: But you got the link. Is jut doing the same sub you have but with every link. Besides, I cannot access those links because it asks for User and Password,

Comment: What you are asking is almost a full develop of code. You are now in the right path! :) . I suggest you to make secondary subs like `Sub GetData()`and `Sub GetAllTables(doc As Object)` adapted to get those tables for each link and combine them with your code. You got the links, you know how to get tables, just design how do you want to combine those tables with your data and you'll have it.

Comment: @OrkhanOrkhan Besides, I suggest you to not share your username and password here in a comment, somebody can make bad use of it.

Comment: you are right :) I just tried already to do that but the case is that I am having some difficulties with that links because of the logging in processes. The web page requires login action in order to show us the data. that is the most difficult part for me ..

Comment: Thank you I deleted the credential information , thank you for warning :)

Comment: For login part, you can find several examples here in stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32364185/excel-vba-login-to-ie-site or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334028/using-vba-to-log-in-to-a-website-and-clear-previous-login-credentials or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32364185/excel-vba-login-to-ie-site or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470634/web-login-using-vba. If you have problems, then design some code and ask a new question here in SO. About this question, if it's already answered, then please mark the answer as right, so the question will be closed.